# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Angular

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Can someone explain how I can get the access token and document urn that are used in the example of Angular Autodesk Forge Viewer? I have a client id and secret, but I haven't figured out how to get these two pieces of information to make this example work. I'm guessing these may be found by a separate call to Autodesk, but I just haven't found the documentation on it yet.

The example I am attempting to follow is at :https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer

Answer (score 2):

Read this https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/2legged/ then choose a backend, eg. Node.js